# Parsing Google contacts feed in Python

Tags: python, xml, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to obtain the name of every contact in Google contact feed using python and based on [Retrieve all contacts from gmail using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883509/retrieve-all-contacts-from-gmail-using-python).

```
social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full' + '?access_token=' + social.tokens + '&max-results=10000'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/12.0.742.112 Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"})
contacts = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()  
contacts_xml = etree.fromstring(contacts)
contacts_list = []
n = 0
for entry in contacts_xml.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
    n = n + 1
    for name in entry.findall('{http://schemas.google.com/g/2005}name'):
        fullName = name.attrib.get('fullName')
        contacts_list.append(fullName)
```

I'm able to obtain the number of contacts `n`, but no luck obtaining the `fullName`. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone needs it, I found the solution to obtain the name from Google Contacts feed:

```
for entry in contacts_xml.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
    for title in entry.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title'):
        name = title.text
        contacts_list.append(name)
```